# How do you use the Facebook Marketing API sandbox to retrieve simulated insights?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I’m working on an application that is going to leverage the Facebook (Meta) Marketing API to retrieve ad campaign insights. I don’t have any real life data to work with so I was hoping to use ‘simulated insights’ aka mock data which was referred to as a future feature in a 2017 article about the Marketing API sandbox mode. Has anybody been able to get simulated insights working? I’ve setup a sandbox account and don’t receive any insights which I somewhat expected without any special arguments or specific endpoint to call. Any help is greatly appreciated